# Hyperledger Composer - Query datetime parameters

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm trying to execute this query with HL Composer v0.19.4. But it always returns an empty array[].

```
query getTransactionsBetweenIntervalMadeByParticipant{
  description: "Get all transactions made by participant between an interval"
statement:
    SELECT org.hyperledger.composer.system.HistorianRecord
    WHERE ((participantInvoking==_$participantInvoking) AND (_$fromTime>transactionTimestamp) AND (_$toTime<transactionTimestamp))
```

Which is the right format of the timestamp that must be passed to the query?

(I tried with *"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.zzz"* and with Unix timestamp but didn't work).

Answer (score 0):

the format is `"2018-05-11T10:42:21.945Z"` (one 'Z') ie 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ' or you can provide 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ' or 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss:ssZ'

as in:

```
var dateString = "2018-01-02T11:42Z"; // DateTime however you build it.

var myDate = new Date(dateString);
```

Not: Obviously doing a `new Date()` won't be really appropriate in a Transaction Processor (non-deterministic code) as its being deployed to a runtime blockchain and knowing when its evaluated after being endorsed/executed is anyone's guess.